# How come JAVA MAIL API works on Android emulator but not on real phone?

Tags: android

I have followed this tutorial from https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/send-email-in-android-using-javamail-api/. I have tested this on my android emulator and it successfully sent an email but when I tried using it on a real android device, it shows an error - javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;"

**GMailSender.java**

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
{
private Session session;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
}

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", Config.MAIL_HOST);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", Config.MAIL_PORT);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", user);

    session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
        }
    });
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
                                  String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/html"));
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setDataHandler(handler);

    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    else
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

    Transport.send(message);
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there something I need to do to make the JAVA MAIL API work on a real android device Or should I use GMAIL API instead?

Comment: Have you tried the other (25, 465) ports?  It's possible your carrier is blocking these to prevent spam from a rogue application.

Comment: @stdunbar I already tried using port 465 and it sent email successfully from the Android Emulator but not a real device. Port 25 seems to be not working on both.